# How to split string after break followed by another tag enclosure?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to explode string using javascript and regex after break `<br>` followed by one of the following tags enclosures `</i>` or `</div>` or `</b>` ?

For example if my string is:

```
var string = "Some text<div><br></div>Second part of the text";
```

or

```
var string = "Some text<b><br></b>Second part of the text";
```

or

```
var string = "Some text<i><br></i>Second part of the text";
```

The output of the string should be:

```
string[0] = "Some text";
string[1] = "Second part of the text";
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *sigh* parsing of html with regex is a bad idea.

Comment: Obligatory bad idea link http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: It doesn't need to be achieved with regex. And it would always be <br/> as it's produced by the WTSWYG editor. Thanks for help...

Comment: How should be the output of the string?

Comment: @Mr_Green I included the desired string into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work :

```
var r = /<i><br><\/i>|<b><br><\/b>|<div><br><\/div>/;
var s = "Some text<i><br></i>Second part of the text";
s.split(r); // ["Some text", "Second part of the text"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The regexp you are looking for is this:

```
/<br\/>(?=(?:(?:<\/b>)|(?:<\/i>)|(?:<\/div>)))/
```

It uses positive lookahead (http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and non-capturing parenthesis.

Working example:
http://jsbin.com/uGIxUZI/1/edit

PS: The examples in your question don't match your answer (< /br> instead of < br/>)

Answer (score 0):

To get only the text part, you can create a dummy element and add that text in to it. Something like this:

```
function getText(txt) {   
    var main = document.getElementById('main');  //can also be "document"
    var div = document.createElement('div');     //dummy element
    div.innerHTML = txt;
    main.appendChild(div);
    var c = div.childNodes;
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].nodeType == 3) {         //condition to filter the text nodes
            arr.push(c[i].data);
        }
    }
    main.removeChild(div);             //remove dummy element
    return arr;                        //return array
}
```

---

```
var str = getText("Some text<div></br></div>Second part of the text");
console.dir(str);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3f4SU/2/)

Comment: I have random number of nodes before I need to split the string. And i need to split it just on the first appearance, ideally with the split method. The final purpose is to make a handlebar helper...

Comment: @hjuster So you want to split it only with the first occurence of the node. right?